# How to use linq to calculate average from grouped data where value > 0 using let

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I need to calculate an average of pretty complicated structure of enuberable data.

I have `var table1Sum` that is joined from two datatables. Another `var table2Sum` is also joined from two datatables. These two tables are joined into third table.

I need to get average of `field3` grouped by `field1` and `field2` but the average calculation should not take into count when `field3 == 0.0`.

I tried

```
var table3 = from d in table1sum.Concat(table2sum)
             group d by new { d.field1, d.field2 } into dg
             let field3Average = dg.Where(g => g.field3 > 0.0).Average()
             select new
             {
             .....
             };
```

but this is not correct syntax for calculating average. I'm using `let` because I need calculated average later on in the `select new` part of my linq query.

(The normal average of all values goes well with `let averageWithZeros = dg.Average(g => g.field3)`.)

Could somebody help me with correct syntax?

Comment: you need to select field 3 after the filter before the average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to average field 3 after the filter

```
 let field3Average = dg.Where(g => g.field3 > 0.0).Average(g => g.field3)
```